# Reshape dataframe wide to long in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a wide data that look like this

```
Name    Date    A   B   C   D
Ben 2020-01-22  1   0   0.0 0.0
Ben 2020-01-23  1   0   0.0 0.0
Ben 2020-01-24  3   0   2.0 0.0
Ben 2020-01-25  3   0   0.0 0.0
Ben 2020-01-26  4   0   1.0 0.0
...     ...             ...
```

And I want to turn it into a format that look like this

```
                   Name         Variable      Value
Date                                                 
2020-01-22         Ben          A             1.0
2020-01-22         Ben          B             0.0
2020-01-22         Ben          C             0.0
2020-01-22         Ben          D             0.0
2020-01-23         Ben          A             1.0
...                ...          ...           ...
```

This is what I've tried

```
pd.melt(df, 
        id_vars="Date", value_vars=["A", "B", "C", "D"],
        var_name="Variable", value_name="Value")
```

And the result look like this

```
        Date    Variable    Value
0   2020-01-22  A           1.0
1   2020-01-23  A           1.0
2   2020-01-24  A           3.0
3   2020-01-25  A           3.0
4   2020-01-26  A           4.0
```

Are there other ways to convert data from wide to long?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
df.melt(id_vars=["Date", "Name"], var_name="Variable", value_name="Value")
```

Output:

```
          Date Name Variable  Value
0   2020-01-22  Ben        A    1.0
1   2020-01-23  Ben        A    1.0
2   2020-01-24  Ben        A    3.0
3   2020-01-25  Ben        A    3.0
4   2020-01-26  Ben        A    4.0
5   2020-01-22  Ben        B    0.0
6   2020-01-23  Ben        B    0.0
7   2020-01-24  Ben        B    0.0
8   2020-01-25  Ben        B    0.0
9   2020-01-26  Ben        B    0.0
10  2020-01-22  Ben        C    0.0
11  2020-01-23  Ben        C    0.0
12  2020-01-24  Ben        C    2.0
13  2020-01-25  Ben        C    0.0
14  2020-01-26  Ben        C    1.0
15  2020-01-22  Ben        D    0.0
16  2020-01-23  Ben        D    0.0
17  2020-01-24  Ben        D    0.0
18  2020-01-25  Ben        D    0.0
19  2020-01-26  Ben        D    0.0
```